Filter data frame into list of data frames
I have a data frame which I want split into several elements of a named list by filtering by year and selecting a single variable.
df <- data.frame(year = sample(rep(2010:2020, times=3)), x = runif(33))

What I want to get is something similar to
yr2010 <- df %>%
    filter(year == 2010) %>%
    select(x) %>%
    as.matrix()

yr2011 <- df %>%
    filter(year == 2011) %>%
    select(x) %>%
    as.matrix()

...

yr2020 <- df %>%
    filter(year == 2020) %>%
    select(x) %>%
    as.matrix()

df_list <- list(yr2010 = yr2010, ..., yr2020 = yr2020)

How can I do that?


base

split(df['x'], paste0("yr", df$year))



dplyr

df %>%
  mutate(year = paste0("yr", year)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>% {
    setNames(group_split(., .keep = FALSE), group_keys(.)$year)
  }

Note: From the document of group_split, it said

group_split() is not stable because you can achieve very similar results by manipulating the nested column returned from tidyr::nest(.by =). That also retains the group keys all within a single data structure. group_split() may be deprecated in the future.



tidyverse

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(year = paste0("yr", year)) %>%  # dplyr
  nest(.by = year) %>%                   # tidyr
  deframe()                              # tibble


Output
# $yr2010
# # A tibble: 3 × 1
#       x
#   <dbl>
# 1 0.327
# 2 0.163
# 3 0.939
# 
# $yr2011
# # A tibble: 3 × 1
#        x
#    <dbl>
# 1 0.202 
# 2 0.0209
# 3 0.862
# ...


Does that work when the column year is scrambled? I edited the question to reflect that.

@amrods yes all my answers deal with it.

A dplyr solution using group_split:
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_split(year, .keep = FALSE) |> 
  setNames(paste0("yr", sort(unique(df$year))))

#<list_of<tbl_df<x:double>>[11]>
#$yr2010
# A tibble: 3 × 1
#       x
#   <dbl>
#1 0.849 
#2 0.845 
#3 0.0853

#$yr2011
# A tibble: 3 × 1
#      x
#  <dbl>
#1 0.394
#2 0.304
#3 0.488
...

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(year = c(2014L, 2012L, 2016L, 2020L, 2013L, 2017L, 
2010L, 2014L, 2018L, 2013L, 2019L, 2018L, 2020L, 2012L, 2011L, 
2020L, 2012L, 2013L, 2015L, 2019L, 2017L, 2018L, 2016L, 2010L, 
2014L, 2016L, 2015L, 2011L, 2015L, 2017L, 2019L, 2010L, 2011L
), x = c(0.536158735398203, 0.835086770122871, 0.37455660966225, 
0.925604712218046, 0.872673955745995, 0.306027633370832, 0.849452404072508, 
0.276228162227198, 0.575324499513954, 0.408695956459269, 0.980199206154794, 
0.0974830950144678, 0.00175619078800082, 0.980167318368331, 0.394283950561658, 
0.830085879191756, 0.651535265613347, 0.699725363403559, 0.736490845214576, 
0.979100176133215, 0.546931945951656, 0.869536967016757, 0.548196423565969, 
0.84485424309969, 0.358381181955338, 0.231132469605654, 0.00961211626417935, 
0.30368754058145, 0.144809128949419, 0.401646558428183, 0.689442926784977, 
0.0852784754242748, 0.488420734880492)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))

